# Add changepoint lines to plot in prophet (R)

Tags: r, facebook-prophet

I am using `prophet` in R (https://facebook.github.io/prophet/), and I would like to overlay changepoints on top of the forecasting plot prophet makes.  Here's my code (`df` is a dataframe containing dates (column `ds`) and values (column `y`):

```
m <- prophet(df)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods=5)
forecast <- predict(m, future)

plot(m, forecast, xlab="Day", ylab="Counts")


i = 0
while (i <= length(m$changepoints.t)) {
  tmp <- m$changepoints[i]
  abline(v=as.POSIXct(tmp), col='red')
  i = i + 1  
 }
```

However, the changepoint lines never show up.  I double-checked that the changepoints are in range of the main plot, and I tried both `as.Date` and `as.POSIXct` in `abline`.  No errors in either case, but no changepoint lines either. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

If you check the class of the plot object:

```
class(plot(m,forecast,xlab="Day", ylab="Counts"))
```

... you'll see that it's a ggplot graphic. Additionally, if you access `m$changepoints` instead of `m$changepoints.t`, you'll find the changepoints of your model already in POSIXct format.

To plot all of your changepoints as vertical lines, you can use `geom_vline` like so:

```
p <- plot(m,forecast,xlab="Day", ylab="Counts")
for (changepoint in m$changepoints) {
  p <- p + geom_vline(xintercept = changepoint)
}
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `prophet` package has a dedicated function for this, `add_changepoints_to_plot`.

In your case, this would do the trick:

```
plot(m, forecast, xlab="Day", ylab="Counts") +
add_changepoints_to_plot(m)
```

See `?add_changepoints_to_plot` for customisations.